Numpy: large number modulo numpy array
I have a large number (>64 Bit) and an array of small numbers.
import numpy as np
n = 375562681772559479679199924760395898982847025172274709141095261928746039609
primes = np.array([2,3,5,7,11])

In an earlier numpy version I could write n % primes, which was significantly faster than list comprehension.
After my latest update I get OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long. Yes, n is too large, but the result isn't.
Is there any way, I can still achieve this in numpy (using its speed)?
To compare, I picked some smaller n of 64 bit. My alternative np.array([n % p for p in primes]) takes about 3 times as long as n % primes.
In my larger use cases, primes are the primes below 1000, i.e. 168 elements.

How large is your list / array of primes?

Note that under the hood, NumPy pre-2.0 will likely use Python's arbitrary integer calculations anyway; the resulting array of n % primes has a dtype of object, not integers, which I suspect is indicative of that.

In your alternative, is primes a list or an array?

Given my second comment, try with primes = np.array([2,3,5,7,11], dtype=object); n % primes. Let us know the timings for that compared to "array from list iteration".

primes consists of the primes below 1000, i.e. 168 elements

And how large are your actual values of n?

Also, why are you using NumPy at all? Do you need it for what you do with the results of this? What are you doing with the results?

I see you were here again. Could you please answer the questions?

n has some 1000s of bits and I ask about numpy because it was faster than other methods I could find.

I can't reproduce that. List comprehension without NumPy was equally fast, both took ~78 μs for n with 3000 bits. Here's my code. What times do you get with that?
